# File input containing string and integer

Tags: c++, arrays, file, file-io

I have a file whose content looks like this :

```
Aadam
50
Aadam
0
Aad
0123
Waleed
12345
```

Now, I need to store first line in a string array and second line into an integer array.
This is the source code that I have written....

```
ifstream infile ("File.txt");
string name [20];
int score [20};
for (int i = 0; !infile.eof(); i++)
            {
                getline(infile, name[i]);
                infile >> scores[i];
            }
```

Well, the program reads first line successfully but after that it does nothing.
I tried another method first, in which I store the integer first as a temporary string and then I convert that string into an integer using "stoi", which worked like a charm. Like this :

```
for (int i = 0; !infile.eof(); i++)
            {
                getline(infile, name[i]);
                string temp;
                getline(infile, temp);
                scores[i] = stoi(temp);
            }
```

But the problem is that I can't use stoi. It works fine in my computer but I have to provide the source code to my teacher who may not have the compiler which supports C++11. Which may be a problem for me.
So I need another way to input data from the file.
So, Kindly if you know a way to do this, please show me the way.

Comment: Also note please what's written here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist of the problem is that if the input contains:

```
Aadam\n
50\n
```

and you do:

```
  getline(infile, name[i]);    // name[i] contains "Hello", \n consumed
  infile >> scores[i];         // scores[i] contains 50
```

then the input still contains:

```
\n
```

that was after the `50`. The `>>` operator with `int` does not consume any trailing newlines or other characters after the number that it extracted.

Then for the next time around the loop, the input stream contains:

```
\n
Aadam\n
0\n
```

and you do:

```
  getline(infile, name[i]);    // name[i] contains "", \n consumed
  infile >> scores[i];         // input failure
```

Since `Aadam` (the second one) cannot be parsed as an `int`, the `>>` operator puts `infile` into a failure state. Your code never clears the failure state nor checks for it, so all subsequent operations fail and your code goes into an infinite loop.

Additional problems are that [using eof() is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong), and (if the reading was fixed) you have a buffer overflow if there are more than 20 pairs of items in your file.

---

To solve the I/O problem you could write it this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    getline(infile , name[i]);
    infile >> scores[i];
    infile.ignore(SIZE_MAX, '\n');

    if ( !infile )
        break;
}
```

The `ignore` line here means that after reading the number, it will consume the remainder of that line.

When the loop finishes, `i` will contain the number of pairs that successfully read. The condition to `break` out of the loop if input fails is important.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "stoi" use "atoi" instead:

```
scores[i] = atoi(temp.c_str());
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi

It's been around since way before C++11.

Comment: And how should that help solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use stoi, you can use string streams instead.

```
std::ifstream infile ("File.txt");
std::string name[20];
int score[20];
for (int i = 0; !infile.eof(); i++){
    getline(infile,name[i]);
    std::string temp;
    getline(infile,temp);

    std::stringstream s; 
    s << temp; 
    int integertemp; 
    s >> integertemp; // This will convert string to integer, just like how it is with iostreams.
    score[i] = integertemp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `getline` after using `>>`.

To solve it you can add this method:

```
istream& eatwhites(istream& stream)
{
    // to define white spaces manually:
    //const string skip=" \t\r\n";
    //while(string::npos != skip.find(stream.peek())){
    //   stream.ignore();
    //}

    //or just use isspace:
    while(isspace(stream.peek())){
        stream.ignore();
    }

    return stream;
}
```

and write each `getline` like this:

```
string name;
getline( eatwhites(infile), name);
```

and also with `cin`:

```
string name;
getline( eatwhites(cin), name);
```

Comment: He want scores as well, not just the names.

Comment: The problem is with `getline` after using `>>`. this fix the problem.